# A simple problem about 2-factor in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

For a given graph G（simple,no direction,connected）,if every vertex has an even degree, then G has a 2-factor（i.e. there are edge-distinct cycles covering all vertices）.
I think I've ever seen this before but I didn't find a proof. Could you please help me with this？

Comment: You're missing the hypothesis that $G$ must be regular. Otherwise, there are graphs for which this does not hold; the simplest is [this one](https://hog.grinvin.org/ViewGraphInfo.action?id=776).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_factorization#2-factorization

Comment: Maybe you are thinking of the fact that there is an Euler circuit if its connected and every vertex has an even degree?

Comment: By induction on the number of edges. If the graph is even then it has a cycle. remove the edges of this cycle and apply the induction hypothesis to the remaining subgraph

Comment: I mean it’s true for 2-regular graphs.

Comment: @mouthethics doesn’t work because the degree contributed from the cycle is lost, which can result in a graph with odd degree.

Comment: @ZacharyHunter A cycle contributes by an even degree to each vertex in it, so you you remove the cycle the parity doesn't change.

Comment: Apologies, I thought the cycles had to be disjoint.

Comment: No they are edges disjoint but they can have vertices in common.

Comment: If they can have vertices in common, then this is not a 2-factor. A 2-factor is a set of vertex-disjoint cycles that cover all vertices of the graph.

Comment: It was my fault that I forgot the condition 'regular'. There's also a mistake in the description -- 2-factor means vertex disjoint cycles covering all vertices（not 'edge distinct' as I mentioned previously）.

Comment: Thank you all! I should learn to use wiki next time :）

Answer (score 3):

By induction of $E(G)$, the number of edges. Let $G$ be a graph as in your question. Then $G$ has a cycle (To show this consider a maximal path in $G$, it must be cycle.) say $C$. Let $F=G\setminus E(C)$. It clear that $F$ is still an even graph, however it may not be connected. Apply the induction hypothesis to each component of $F$ and you're done.

Comment: I mention for completeness that this is a decomposition of the edges, not of the vertices; the resulting cycles are not necessarily vertex-disjoint. (This is not the standard definition of a 2-factor, but it may still be what the question is about, who knows.)